# Почему вылетает после ввода второго элемента динамической структуры?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Есть функция ввода новой книги (автор, название, год, цена) `NewBook`.
После ввода второй книги программа вылетает. Не знаю, в чем причина (наверное, что-то где-то с выделением памяти, но где я что-то не так написал - не знаю). Перед этим сделал две точно таких же задания, и там все было нормально, а тут вылетает. В дебаггере смотрел - вроде бы все OK. Код кидаю весь.
Вторая книга вводится, но после ввода вылетает.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Books {
    char *author;
    char *nazva;
    int year;
    int price;
};
void NewBook(Books*&, int&);
void Deleting(Books*&, int&);
void Del(Books*&, int);
void Print(Books*&, int&);

void main()
{
    Books *boo = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        NewBook(boo, size);

    }
    Print(boo, size);
    Deleting(boo, size);
}
void Deleting(Books*&boo, int &size)
{
    if (boo = NULL)
        cout << "Its okay=) You have'nt any book \n;)" << endl;
    else
    {

    }
}
void Del(Books *&boo, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[]boo[i].author;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[]boo[i].nazva;
    delete[]boo;
}
void Print(Books *&boo, int &size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << boo[i].author << "\t" << boo[i].nazva << "\t" << boo[i].year << "\t" << boo[i].price << " UAH" << endl;
    }
}
void NewBook(Books*&boo, int &size) {
    if (boo == NULL) {
        boo = new Books[size + 1];
        cout << "Author? " << endl;
        char*aut = new char[40];
        cin.getline(aut, 40);
        boo[size].author = new char[strlen(aut) + 1];
        strcpy_s(boo[size].author, strlen(aut) + 1, aut);
        //delete[]aut;

        cout << "Nazva? " << endl;
        char*aut1 = new char[40];
        cin.getline(aut1, 40);
        boo[size].nazva = new char[strlen(aut1) + 1];
        strcpy_s(boo[size].nazva, strlen(aut1) + 1, aut1);

        cout << "Year? " << endl;
        cin >> boo[size].year;

        cout << "Price?" << endl;
        cin >> boo[size].price;
    }
    else {
        Books *tmp = new Books[size + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tmp[i].author = new char[strlen(boo[i].author) + 1];
            strcpy_s(tmp[i].author, strlen(boo[i].author) + 1, boo[i].author);

            tmp[i].nazva = new char[strlen(boo[i].nazva) + 1];
            strcpy_s(tmp[i].nazva, strlen(boo[i].nazva) + 1, boo[i].nazva);

            tmp[i].price = boo[i].price;
            tmp[i].year = boo[i].year;
        }
        cout << "Author? " << endl;
        char*aut = new char[40];
        cin.get();
        cin.getline(aut, 40);
        tmp[size + 1].author = new char[strlen(aut) + 1];
        strcpy_s(tmp[size + 1].author, strlen(aut) + 1, aut);
        //delete[]aut;

        cout << "Nazva? " << endl;
        char*aut2 = new char[40];
        cin.getline(aut2, 40);
        tmp[size + 1].nazva = new char[strlen(aut2) + 1];
        strcpy_s(tmp[size + 1].nazva, strlen(aut2) + 1, aut2);

        cout << "Year? " << endl;
        cin >> tmp[size + 1].year;

        cout << "Price?" << endl;
        cin >> tmp[size + 1].price;

        Del(boo, size);
        /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete[]boo[i].author;
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         delete[]boo[i].nazva;
         delete[]boo;*/
        boo = tmp;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Comment: а конкретно где вылетает ?

Comment: А оно не компилируется. С другой стороны, не вижу причин, почему здесь тег c++11, если по хорошему, пора уже заводить тег "с+" (да, именно с одним плюсом).

Comment: Для начала надо исправить синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Забавная у вас проверка `if (boo = NULL)`. Впрочем, проблема не в ней, до нее не доходит...

Comment: @KoVadim, да-да, `c+` :) А вообще интересно что это - какой-то флэшмоб исходников, где у функций куча параметров-ссылок на указатели? Или какой-то новый видеокурс вышел?

Comment: `Author?`, `Nazva?`, `Year?`, `Price?` ... найди лишнее :-D

Comment: @KoVadim я думаю, и `c--` сгодится.

Comment: @alexolut А вот тут не надо, `C--` - был такой проект времен DOS'a - маленький, урезанный - но очень шустрый C... С этим кодом - ничего общего :)

Comment: Автор, если вы хотите, чтоб в вашем коде копались - он должен быть прилично структурирован, хорошо откомментирован, разбит на функции, а не куча выделений и копирований памяти одной кишкой... Правда, когда вы это сделаете - ошибки уйдут сами собой: вы их сразу будете видеть. То, что у вас сейчас - пример **антистиля**, как писать нельзя...

Comment: Если очень кратко, то ошибка в строках, которые содержат `tmp[size + 1]`. Там должно быть `tmp[size]`. Классическая ошибка выхода за границы массива. Об утечках памяти и других бяках я просто молчу.

Answer (score 1):

Я переписал это все, сделав его более плюсовым, чем оно было раньше. Оно даже стало короче.

Конечно, опытные плюсовики набегут и скажут, что это никакой не с++:) и можно красивее, но боюсь, в этом случае код будет непонятен не только @anonimoys , но и его преподавателю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Book {
    public:
        string author;
        string nazva;
        int year;
        int price;

        void print()
        {
            cout << author << "\t" << nazva << "\t" << year << "\t" << price << endl;
        }
};

class Books
{
    private:
        vector<Book> mBooks;
    public:
        void print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mBooks.size(); i++) {
                mBooks[i].print();
            }
        }

        void add(Book b)
        {
            mBooks.push_back(b);
        }

};


Book inputBook()
{
    Book b;

    cout << "Author? " << endl;
    getline(cin, b.author);

    cout << "Name? " << endl;
    getline(cin, b.nazva);

    cout << "Year? " << endl;
    cin >> b.year;

    cout << "Price?" << endl;
    cin >> b.price;
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    return b;
}


int main()
{
    Books boo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Book b = inputBook();
        boo.add(b);
    }
    boo.print();
    return 0;
}
```